# Changing Style of Selection works but isnt reflected in the document ribbon bar

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following code in my macro to test this issue.

```
With Selection
    .InsertAfter " End1"
    .Style = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleStrong
    .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    .InsertAfter " TEST2"
    .Style = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleNormal
End With
```

This code will insert " End1" after the selected text, change the style to strong. Then it will collapse to the end and insert " TEST2" and change the style to normal.

This does actually happen in the document correctly, however the style on the document still stays strong in the styles menu for the part that should be normal. Actually the entire line is set to strong style.

Here is an image to illustrate. Is there something I am missing? Is the style not actually set to Normal for the second insert, but only the formatting changed?

[image]

I am using word 2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be because the "**style type**" attribute of wdStyleStrong is "**character**" and the attribute of "wdStyleNormal" is "**paragraph**", and the character setting has **priority** over the paragraph, and the later inserted text will inherit the previous formatting value. Therefore, if you just want to use the style of "wdStyleNormal", you can rewrite it as follows:

```vb
With Selection
    .InsertAfter " End1"
    .Style = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleStrong
    .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    .InsertAfter " TEST2"
    .ClearFormatting
    '.Style = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleNormal
End With
```

use **ClearFormatting** method instead of using the Style property.Or you may use a enumeration constant Style which Type attribute is wdStyleTypeCharacter , or define a Style by yourself ,set Style.Type = wdStyleTypeCharacter , instead of using the built-in WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleNormal

[Style.Priority property (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Word.Style.Priority)

[Style.Type property (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.style.type)

Sorry I only have the traditional Chinese version：

[image: wdStyleNormal Type]

[image: wdStyleStrong Type]

---

The **heading** style in MS Word is also set by the unit of "paragraph" (meaning the heading style, the WdStyleType attribute value and the style of "text"(as shown in your previous pic is name of "**Normal**") are **wdStyleTypeParagraph**, not "**wdStyleTypeCharacter**"), so you set the style of a word/phrase text to "heading", then the whole paragraph where the insertion point is located will be set to the style of the heading. So if you set the style of a word/phrase to "title", the whole paragraph where the insertion point is located will be set to the style of the title.
If the type of the style set (the value of WdStyleType) is wdStyleTypeCharacter, then ONLY the value of the character style will be recorded as a character, and if the type is wdStyleTypeParagraph , it will be set for the whole paragraph to that Style. **The WdStyleType enumeration for type property of a certain style** should be the key to your problem.

Comment: This seems to work, however I am also having issues with using styles of the same type. See new edit to original question.

Comment: As I mentioned at the end of the previous post. THANKS

Comment: I created a new question regarding the additional issue I was having. What you explained makes sense, but doesn't track with what I see when I preform the same change manually.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76178613/why-doesnt-style-apply-correctly-to-two-different-inserted-texts

Comment: All right, it should be done now.