# Apply two different styles within the same paragraph using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to insert two words, one after the other. Each one having a different style.

This is the code I tried. Both pieces of text have the same style ("Heading 1").

```vb
    With Selection
        .InsertAfter " Test1"
        .Style = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        .InsertAfter " Test2"
        .Style = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading2
    End With
```

It seems the second word is getting only the formatting of the style, instead of the style itself.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/kzBP1Xh]

Another example to illustrate the issue. I noticed if I have two words, I select the first word and then execute the following code.

```
Selection.Style = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1
```

It has the same outcome. The selected word has the formatting for Heading 1 but it still says Normal in the style box.

I can change the style manually without VBA.
[image]

Note: Using Word 2019.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what style the paragraph has before you apply the style. But the issue probably stems from this: Many built-in Word styles are _linked_: they're both character and paragraph styles. When you select part of a paragraph and apply a linked style, the character attributes and style name are applied to that portion.

Comment: They are all Normal before any styling is applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A paragraph can only have one paragraph style. To apply additional styles to parts of the content of that paragraph it is necessary to apply a character style.

Many built-in styles are *linked* styles. Although you only see a single entry in the styles gallery there are two styles, with the second having the " Char" suffix to indicate it is a character style. You will not see this style in the UI.

When applying a linked style in the UI Word makes the decision of which of the two styles to apply according to context.

***When you apply styles in VBA it is up to you to apply the correct style.***

For your example the code would be:

```
With Selection
    .InsertAfter " Test1"
    .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading1).NameLocal & " Char"
    .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    .InsertAfter " Test2"
    .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading2).NameLocal & " Char"
End With
```

Comment: I still don't fully understand how it is possible to set two styles in the same paragraph vai the UI though. (See my second image in my question). That is clearly one paragraph (with CR at the end), but it also clearly has two styles selected. This is what's confusing me the most. Are you saying that one of the styles is not actually being applied (only the character formatting of the other style?)

Comment: Additionally when I run the code above I get the error message on line 3 saying "Item with specified name does not exist". (I assume it means the style with " Char" at the end.

Comment: @ChristopherTownsend - A paragraph can have any number of styles applied to it *but only one paragraph style*. Any style applied to only part of a paragraph, whether by VBA or the UI, must be a *character* style (see e.g. Emphasis or Strong) and will only apply font formatting.

Comment: @ChristopherTownsend - I do not get any error when running the code.

Comment: Are you running in word 2019?

Comment: I am running O365, but the code I posted will work in Word 2007 and later, though I don't know about on a Mac

Comment: Does it still work for you if you open a new document, and execute that code? It only works for me if I have some text in the document that already uses either Heading 1 or Heading 2 style. It looks like the style with the suffix " Char" will only be created in the background and linked to the original when the original style is used. 
I can also see it doesn't exist in the ActiveDocument.Styles collection until this happens. Can you confirm this? (Currently testing on O365 Enterprise)

Comment: @ChristopherTownsend - works for me in a brand new document, though I do have a customised Normal template which may explain why the styles exist.

Comment: Yea its strange, but nomatter what I do the linked " Char" style only gets created when the original style is used in the document. Until then Normal is considered the linked style. Thanks for the explanation and help though, I finally understand whats going on under the hood a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

My best solution for this so far is to use InsertStyleSeparator to seperate the different text styles. If anyone else has a better solution please feel free to post it, however this was the only way I could get it to work.

```
With Selection
    .InsertAfter " Test1"
    .Style = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1
    .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    .InsertStyleSeparator
    .InsertAfter " Test2"
    .Style = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading2
End With
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.insertstyleseparator

## Final Answer :

While knowing about the InsertStyleSeperator could be useful in some scenarios, knowing how the styles/linked styles work is much better practice so @TimothyRylatt's answer is the correct answer here.

I  recommend reading this post for more context on how they work.
https://office-watch.com/2021/word-styles-from-the-beginning/

I did have an issue where the character linked style did not exist in the document before using it, however I was able to solve this by first changing to the paragraph style (which must force word to create the character style and link it to the original), then I was able to use the character style.

```
    With Selection
        .InsertAfter " Test1"
        .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading1)
        .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading1).NameLocal & " Char"
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        .InsertAfter " Test2"
        .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading2)
        .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading2).NameLocal & " Char"
    End With
```

Answer (score 1):

### Timothy Rylatt's answer is brief and clear

I didn't see it until after posted my code to update.Thanks very much.
We can check out what he said about **linked** and **char and paragraph** in here:
[image]

###### [InsertStyleSeparator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.insertstyleseparator?source=docs) method shown by Christopher Townsend's answer should NOT be a good way to do.

### Concept

#### When using an object and its properties, pay attention to its effective range, that is, the **execution unit**.

If you want to use an object, you should know its **effective range**, i.e., the **execution unit** , such as the life range of the variable or what the **object** you want to operate is.
Therefore, the execution unit is the **paragraph** style that is meaningless or not meaningful or correct for the object that is the **character** of the operation. This is a bit like logic gone awry.
[As I said before,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76169107/changing-style-of-selection-works-but-isnt-reflected-in-the-document-ribbon-bar/76169284#76169284) if you need to operate on a character or phrase, you should choose to operate on a character style, not on a paragraph style. If you want to have a style that works on characters with a font setting like the title style, you should find another or define a new style that works by yourself, not just apply the built-in title style. it makes sense and be logically.

> However when I change the style manually without vba, it works fine.

That should be because when you do it manually, the program running behind **Word** determines whether to do the whole paragraph or just the words based on the style you've chosen. (And when you write your own code, Word doesn't intervene to make that determination.)
In other words, when you click on the **Heading** style, Word will think that you want to operate on a whole **paragraph**, and will naturally apply the title style to the whole paragraph where the insertion point is located. But if you run VBA, because you have first selected the scope to be executed only words (the **object** is **Selection**), and then only set the value of Selection value not of the Paragrapth object. If you want to change this situation, then the **object** should be **Paragraph** (i.e. *Selection.Paragraphs(1)*), *not* **Selection** as you have written) , or the style displayed in the ribbon bar above will not identify the paragraph as a Heading style paragraph ,and the selected style will be a new style based on the formatting of the character you set, and **the name of the style** is usually composed of the various formatting values that make it up and it should be add in the list of the Style box like the image show below.Sure , it's name will not be the **Heading**(in Tranditional Chinese it is the two characters "**標題**").
[image]
**I only have the tranditional Chinese version.*

### Solution

In my traditional Chinese version Word , it can be like that:

```vb
With Selection
    Dim styledChar As String
    styledChar = " 字元"
    .InsertAfter " Test1"
    Rem IF FIRST TIME TO USE THE STYLE In A DOC WHERE SELECTION IS , NEXT LINE IS necessary
    .Style = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1
    .Style = .Document.Styles(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1) & styledChar
    .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
'    .InsertStyleSeparator
    .ClearFormatting
    .InsertAfter " Test2"
    Rem IF FIRST TIME TO USE THE STYLE In A DOC WHERE SELECTION IS , NEXT LINE IS necessary
    .Style = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading2
    .Style = .Document.Styles(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading2) & styledChar
End With
```

it seems that the **.InsertStyleSeparator** method is not apply in this context.

You can place the insertion point inside the text where you manually set style , and type "?Selection.Style" in the immediate window in VBE and enter to see what the value in your version, to determine the value of *styledChar* in my code above.In mine ,it is

[image]

**The KEY** in this situation is the **property** like :
[image]
[image]

### concluding

in my traditinal Chinese version is name "**文字階層格式設定**" ( or the value of the **字元樣式** property like pic above shown in yellow circle), it is the point that determine what will be select in ribbon bar. However I still not get the corresponding syntax in VBA.