# How can one change the style of a text in a highlighted cell in a table in MS Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a table in MS Word.
I want to change the style of a few cells to a defined style in the document -- "NewStyle09".

If i have to change the style of a selected text, I can do the following:
`Selection.Range.Style = "NewStyle09"`

However, I am unable to extend this concept to changing the style of a highlighted cell in a table.

Can you please help.

Update:

When I select more than one contiguous cells, the following code changes the style of text in the other cells that are adjacent to the ones that i select. However, i only want the cells that i select to change its style.

```
'change style of table cell
Sub TargetSelectedCells()
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim rng As Range
    
    ' Check if a table is selected
    If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
        Set tbl = Selection.Tables(1)
        
        ' Check if cells are selected
        If Selection.Cells.Count > 0 Then
            Set rng = Selection.Range
            
            ' Do something with the selected cells
            ' For example, change the background color
            rng.Style = "HON White"
            'rng.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorLightBlue
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If you use `Selection` in VBA (Word or Excel), you can safely assume that you are doing something wrong. That said:  `ThisDocument.Tables(1).Cells(1).Range.Style = ThisDocument.Styles("NewStyle09")`

Comment: Oh good grief. Just record a macro and use that to guide you writing your own code

Comment: Note the style have paragraph level and character level, if you just want to apply to a cell , you should use the character level one for your *"NewStyle09"* . Refer to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76169107/changing-style-of-selection-works-but-isnt-reflected-in-the-document-ribbon-bar/76169284?noredirect=1#comment134334245_76169284). <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76178613/why-cant-i-apply-two-different-styles-within-the-same-paragraph-using-vba>

Answer (score 1):

You can reference the cell of a selection use `Selection.Range.Cells(1)`

```vb
Sub formatSelectedCell()
Dim rg As Word.Range
Set rg = Selection.Range

If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
    rg.Cells(1).Range.Style = "NewStyle09"
End If

End Sub
```

The code checks if selection is within table.

To change style of each selected cell use this code:

```vb
Sub formatSelectedCell()
Dim rg As Word.Range
Set rg = Selection.Range

Dim c As Cell
If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
    For Each c In rg.Cells
        c.Range.Style = "NewStyle09"
    Next
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is it is changing the style of the adjacent cells in other columns as well.

Comment: @Nosail: Maybe you should elaborate what you mean with *"a few cells"* and how you want to identify those.

Comment: Are those cells merged? Because with a simple table - w/o merged cells - only the cell with the selection is handled.

Comment: OK. So, i am not facing the latter issue anymore. But a new problem. This is what i wish to do: i want to highlight the text in two or more contiguous cells and change their style. when i select those cells, and apply the macro `Selection.Range.Cells(1).Range.Style = "NewStyle09"`, it changes only the style of the first cell. How can i get it to change the style of all the cells that i select.

Comment: And i think that is because of `Cells(1)`. How can i target all the cells that a user selects?

Comment: ah so here is my finding: When i create a table in Word, it works fine; however, the table on which i am working is a table i copied over from Excel, and that is leading to the issue where upon selecting a particular cell and applying the macro, adjacent cells are also having their style changed.

Comment: I can't reproduce that. Again the question: are there merged cells?

Comment: @Nosail Note the style have paragraph level and character level, if you just want to apply to a cell , you should use the character level one for your "NewStyle09" .

Answer (score 0):

> When I select more than one contiguous cells, the following code changes the style of text in the other cells that are adjacent to the ones that i select. However, i only want the cells that i select to change its style.

> Note the style have **paragraph** level and **character** level, if you just want to apply to a cell , you should use the **character level** one for your "NewStyle09" . Refer to

[Why can't I apply two different styles within the same paragraph using vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76178613/why-cant-i-apply-two-different-styles-within-the-same-paragraph-using-vba)

[Changing Style of Selection works but isnt reflected in the document ribbon bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76169107/changing-style-of-selection-works-but-isnt-reflected-in-the-document-ribbon-bar/76169284?noredirect=1#comment134334245_76169284)

Did you check what I reminded you before first?

Could you give me a sample to test, especially including the style "**NewStyle09**" you defined by yourself?