# VSTO: MS-Word Range-Styling Affects Entire Line

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, word-addins, word-style

I'm using C# over VS2022, to write a VSTO add-in for Word, intended to auto-style **in-line** text-portions of a certain pre-defined format, e.g. to apply a (pre-defined) style to any text in brackets.

To exemplify the desired result, notice how a special *(italic style)* is applied to bracketed portions of the following text:

> **This** *(part in brackets)* **should demonstrate the** *(desired)* **result**.

In code, after a target-portion is found, it is wrapped by a `Range` object, like so:

```
Range oRange = doc.Range(iStartIndex, iEndIndex);
```

This works well - range encapsulates exactly the required sequence of characters.
But, when calling `oRange.set_Style (styleName)`, style is applied **to the entire line** in which this range lies.

Behavior is the same:

1. for various languages and font-types.
2. even if the `set_Style` method is used like so: `object szStyle="Heading 1"; oRange.set_Style (ref szStyle);`
3. even if the `set_Style` method is used like so: `oRange.set_Style (doc.Styles[styleName]);`

I've found a close, yet-unanswered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73489544/1117614).

Comment: If your style is a *paragraph style*, it *will* be applied to the whole paragraph. If "Linked Styles" is disabled in Word (unusual, but possible) then even a style such as Heading 1, which is normally a linked style, will act as a paragraph style. I.e. I yoi should be able to apply a *character style* to part of a line/paragraph, but if that doesn't work, there must be another problem.

Comment: Thanks, @jonsson, for your response. The style I'm applying is defined as "Linked (paragraph and character)", and MS-Word's styling-settings enable "Linked Styles".
So, we're after that "another problem" you've mentioned.
If any clue comes to mind, I'd happy to hear (or read) it. Thanks again.

Comment: So just out of interest, what if the style *is* a character style?

Comment: Just redefined your style as @jonsson mentioned should be fine. Refer to my previous discussion. <https://stackoverflow.com/a/76169284/8249058> <https://stackoverflow.com/a/76179021/8249058> And perhaps you can define your own method(function) to apply the format you want, without the need to involve the limitations of the Style object.

Comment: Indeed, styling is performed successfully to the target-range only, if style-type is *Character*.
I would expect "Linked" to be suitable as well, but I should probably lower my expectations in this field :-)

Comment: Thank you, "jonsson" and "Oscar Sun", for your assistance. Much obliged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue was caused due to applied style's type.
When it was anything other than **Character**, style was applied to the entire line.
Only **Character**-type styles could be successfully applied to an in-line `Range`.