# Replacing Style for a specific words

Tags: vba, ms-word

I got a MS-Word text which is assigned to style = "Standard". I want to assign style = "Standard_Bold" if a word within that text is equal to "Text".

Here is the code I tried out which will assign the style "Standard_Bold" to the complete text instead of only the specific word.

```
Sub replaceStyle(doc as Document)

With doc.Content.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Text = "Text"
    .Replacement.Style = doc.Styles("Standard_Bold").NameLocal
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With

End Sub
```

If I change the `.Replacement.Style` line to `.Replacement.Font.Bold = True` then it works for only the specific word. Would be very happy if someone help me to get the desired result.

Comment: Evidently your style, "Standard_Bold", has been defined as a paragraph style. To be applied to only part of a paragraph it needs to be a character style.

Comment: Just like *Timothy Rylatt* said. Plz refer to my previous answers and discussion: <https://stackoverflow.com/a/76169284/8249058>
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76178613/why-cant-i-apply-two-different-styles-within-the-same-paragraph-using-vba>

Comment: Thanks @TimothyRylatt that was the problem, I had to add doc.Styles.Add Name:="Standard_Bold" Type:=wdStyleTypeCharacter